# Automatic site setup with powershell throws several errors

Tags: powershell, iis-7

first and foremost *I am NOT a Powershell dev* so I'm a little over my head here, if this was BASH it would have been done by now....

I'm getting several errors that I don't really understand the what or why of,

[image: Errors]

I believe that maybe $vars cannot be interpreted in the way that I am trying to use? idk...
If someone WITH powershell knowledge could lend an assist and educate this poor linux guy, I would be very grateful...

I would expect this to register and load a new (empty) site with IIS based of the input params provided.

Here's my PS1

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define the variables.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
Param (
    [string]$InetSiteName = $( Read-Host "Site Name" ),
    [int]$InetSitePort    = $( Read-Host "Site Port" ),
    [string]$InetPhysPath = $( $env:SystemDrive + "\inetpub\wwwroot" )
)


Import-Module "WebAdministration"

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Check for empty.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
if(-not($InetSiteName)) { Throw "Site name cannot be empty..." }
if(-not($InetSitePort)) { Throw "Site port cannot be empty..." }
if(-not($InetPhysPath)) { Throw "Path name cannot be empty..." }

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configure and register.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
New-Item IIS:\Sites\$InetSiteName -physicalPath $InetPhysPath -bindings @{ protocol="http";bindingInformation=":"+$InetSitePort+":"+$InetSiteName } 
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$InetSiteName -name applicationPool -value BenAPI
Start-WebSite $InetSiteName

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
$webclient = New-Object Net.WebClient 
$webclient.DownloadString("http://localhost:$InetSitePort/");

$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.Visible = $true 
$ie.Navigate("http://localhost:$InetSitePort/");
```

Comment: Looks like a part of it was I need `Import-Module "WebAdministration"` prior to my SET ? Still many errors though, will update code to reflect my change

Comment: For starters you need to use `-Path` not `-PhysicalPath` with New-Item...

Comment: I think your module import will give you `IIS:\` as a PSDrive too

Comment: @JNK that give me these errors http://pastebin.com/e8g7XHMb I don't know what a PSDrive is?

Comment: @JNK **-PhysicalPath** is an extension of **New-Item** added by the IIS7 snap-in.

Comment: @ehime ...which begs the question, have you [installed the snap-in](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/installing-the-iis-powershell-snap-in)? If so, try `Add-PSSnapIn WebAdministration`.

Comment: @AdiInbar `Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'WebAdministration' is not installed on this machine.` ?? I don't see it anywhere on the link you gave me though

Comment: @AdiInbar Runnin `Import-Module "WebAdministration"` from a powershell does NOT throw errors though?

Comment: Use New-WebSite rather than New-item

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I also need to set port and I don't think this will allow the bindings to do it

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you could remove your "check if null"-tests by adding `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]` before each parameter in param. Ex `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$InetSiteName = ...., [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$NextParam = ...` :)

Comment: @ehime - Did running your script in administrator mode didn't help you? It works for me. Checkpoint - 1) Result of 'get-module -ListAvailable' must contain WebAdministration. 2) Must have BenAPI app pool. 3) remove $InetSiteName from bindings ,i.e, use -bindings @{ protocol="http";bindingInformation=":"+$InetSitePort+":"}

Comment: @Nitesh it is running in Admin mode, and it did not make a difference http://pastebin.com/tGnNEuAH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the real answer was that I didn't have a real pool created, here's my updated code...

Thanks Everyone

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Checking Execution Policy
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
#$Policy = "Unrestricted"
$Policy = "RemoteSigned"
If ((get-ExecutionPolicy) -ne $Policy) {
  Write-Host "Script Execution is disabled. Enabling it now"
  Set-ExecutionPolicy $Policy -Force
  Write-Host "Please Re-Run this script in a new powershell enviroment"
  Exit
}

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define the variables.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
[string]$InetSiteName = $( Read-Host "Site Name" )
[int]$InetSitePort    = $( Read-Host "Site Port" )
[string]$InetPhysPath = $( $env:SystemDrive + "\inetpub" )

$PoolName = "BenAPI"

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Loading IIS Modules
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
Import-Module "WebAdministration"

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Test or Create App Pool
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
if (!(Test-Path "IIS:\AppPools\$PoolName" -pathType container))
{
    # Create pool
    $appPool = New-Item "IIS:\AppPools\$PoolName"
    $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value "v4.0"
}

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configure and register.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
$WebRoot = New-Item "$InetPhysPath\$InetSiteName" -type Directory
New-Item IIS:\Sites\$InetSiteName -physicalPath $WebRoot -bindings @{ protocol="http";bindingInformation="*:"+$InetSitePort+":" }

Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$InetSiteName -name applicationPool -value BenAPI
Set-Content "$WebRoot\default.htm" "Test Page: $InetSiteName"

Start-WebSite $InetSiteName

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("http://localhost:$InetSitePort/");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because "WebAdministration" module is not getting loaded.  
 Run Powershell as Administrator so that "WebAdministration" module gets imported successfully.

[image]

Then Go to location where you have saved the script to run the script

```
PS C:\> cd 'C:\Users\jDaniel\Documents'
PS C:\Users\jDaniel\Documents> .\iis-site.ps1
```

There is a step to step guide [Here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools) - how to create Web-Sites, Web Applications, Virtual Directories and Application Pools in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I create a new site:

```
New-WebSite -Name $InetSiteName -port $InetSitePort -id 555 -PhysicalPath "$InetPhysPath" -HostHeader $InetSiteName
```

if you need more binding you can use:

```
New-WebBinding -Name $InetSiteName -Port $InetSitePort2 -HostHeader $InetSiteName2
```